# inverse distance weighting interpolation

Tags: c++, algorithm, interpolation

I would like to compute a weight as reciprocal of a distance for something like [inverse distance weighting interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting).

```
double wgt = 0, wgt_tmp, result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   wgt_tmp = 1.0/dist[i];
   wgt += wgt_tmp;
   result += wgt_tmp * values[i];
}
results /= wgt;
```

However the distance can be `0` and I need to make the weight suitable for computation. If there is only one distance `dist[i]` is `0`, I would like its corresponding value `values[i]` to be **dominant**. If there are several distances are `0`, I would like to have their values to **contribute equally** to the result. Also even if `dist[i]` is not zero but very small, I would like to have a reasonable criterion to check it and deal with it. Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any way besides piecewise - you need a different function than reciprocal distance for small distances. The simplest thing would be to just chop off the top:

```
modified_dist[i] = dist[i] < MIN_DIST ? MIN_DIST : dist[i]
```

but you could replace that with something still decreasing if you want, like `(MIN_DIST + dist[i])/2`.

Comment: +1: A specific solution. It should be stressed that the choice is totally arbitrary. The question cannot be answered "objectively".

Comment: Yup, very true. `MIN_DIST` provides a lot of flexibility, and the linear map can be fiddled with - a general form would be `(dist[i] - MIN_DIST) * k + MIN_DIST`, with `k < 1` but not so small that `dist[i] = 0` maps to something too small to divide by...

Comment: Thanks! Does it sound unreasonable if I set MIN_DIST=DBL_EPSILON and MAX_DIST=1.0/DBL_EPSILON when the problem context is not known beforehand?

Comment: I think you want to be a lot more conservative than that - you need wiggle room for all your later operations on `1/distance`. It'd really be best to have an idea of the context, too - in most situations, you can have a pretty good idea of a distance so small it doesn't matter. For example, why bother with a picometer cutoff when you're dealing with cars and a centimeter will do just fine?

Answer (score 6):

If there is a zero-distance, there is no need of interpolation since you have a perfect match!

inside the for-loop:

```
if(dist[i] == 0.) return values[i];
```

Answer (score 5):

Come up with definitions of "dominant", "very small" and "deal with it". Then, translate them into code.

Comment: +1: I approve of general solutions. See my answer for an example or two.